# Protect a document based on its field values in Firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

my firestore data structure is the following. I have a collection of routines and a collection of users. Each routine document has a uid tied to a user. Trying to set security rules so that a user can only edit their own routines and edit their own user details. However, I'm quite stuck at this point. The below is what I have so far.

The `{routine}.uid` is improper syntax, but just trying to illustrate what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /routines/{routine} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == {routine}.uid
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the contents of a document in order to determine its access, you will need to use `resource` in your rules.  I strongly suggest reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) about that.  `resource.data` contains a map of fields from the document being protected by the rule:

```
    match /routines/{routine} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Went through the documentation and made the suggested change. However, doesn't seem to work for me. I'm on an account and can't make any edits or write. Log just says missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Without seeing the query, and that it matches your rules, it's not possible to know for sure what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still relatively new to swift. What query are you referring to? I'm not sure what I would post here to help clarify the situation. I can't quite post all of my code and I don't think the error message would help either?

Comment: You must have some code that queries Firestore, otherwise these rules wouldn't be helpful at all.